# What is "nuclear-pub" device on Android?

Tags: android, device, google-play

When i go on the Developer Console of Google Play Store, in the section "Device Statistics" i see all types of devices that have installed the app.

In this list, there is a device called "nuclear-pub".

Is anyone, know what is hidden behind this device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AdapterDeviceID: A13MID. | AdapterDescription: 'Model: 'A13MID', Product: 'nuclear_pub', Manufacturer: 'unknown', Hardware: 'sun5i''. |  | unknown A13MID | softwinners/nuclear_pub/nuclear-pub:4.0.3/IML74K/20120428:eng/test-keys
ycc_rgb_convert_argb!!!
```

found [here](https://crash-analysis.mozilla.com/rkaiser/2012-07-01/fna-release-14.0-devices-raw.csv)

Its a 7" Tablet called A 13 Mid from a Manufacteur called Allwinner - running ICS.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone modified the device name in a custom rom.